# What could the appropriate Xpath location for Selenium for below HTML?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, contains

Hi Guys _ I need to help to figure out the correct Xpath location to extract all links from below HTML. I have tried lot of combinations, including a lot of Google help but with no solution. HTML looks like below -

```
<div id="fullwidth" class="destLists">
<h1 class="specials" style="padding:0 0 0 30px; background: transparent url(http://q-ec.bstatic.com/static/img/icons/destination_24/48b021a6cd8fa7532053cf41b4cf7a1dce15458a.png) no-repeat 2px 2px;">Destinations</h1>
<div class="description deslast">
<p class="firstpar" style="margin-bottom: 1.2em">
<ul class="destLinks">
<a name="accomodations"/>
<h3>
<table class="general" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
<div class="toTop">
<a name="landmarks"/>
<h3>
<table class="general" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
<div class="toTop">
<a name="districts"/>
<h3>
<table class="general" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
<div class="toTop">
<a name="hotels"/>
<h3>
<table class="general" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<td width="50%">
<a href="/hotel/in/clarks-shiraz.en-us.html?sid=94c48c83993c829d5d7f07ba57314600;dcid=4">Hotel Clarks Shiraz</a>
<br/>
<a href="/hotel/in/courtyard-by-marriott-agra.en-us.html?sid=94c48c83993c829d5d7f07ba57314600;dcid=4">Courtyard by Marriott Agra</a>
```

I want to extract all href links which starts with - /hotel/ or contains - hotel. Below is what I have but it doesn't work.

```
List<WebElement> hotelElements = driver.findElementsByXPath("//*[@id='fullwidth' and contains(href, 'hotel')]/div/*/tbody/*/*/a");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it OK to use CSS Selector? I know you asked specifically for an XPath but I generally try to avoid XPaths unless absolutely necessary (99% of the time they aren't) because they are more error prone, fragile, and slower than CSS selectors.

Try this

```
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a[href*='hotel']"));
for (WebElement link : links)
{
    System.out.println(link.getAttribute("href"));
}
```

It gets all `A` tags that have hrefs that contain (*=) 'hotel'. The loop just dumps the hrefs from each found element to the console. You can do whatever you need from there.

There are other variations of this if you want to separate the hrefs that start with '/hotel/' (^=) vs the ones that contain 'hotel' (*=). See this [CSS Selector reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors).

---

EDIT 1

Since you already marked this as the answer... Andrew just provided the XPath that you need but his code needed some tweaking. You can use his `.findElements()` line with the rest of my code and it should work.

Try this

```
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElementsByXPath(".//a[contains(href, 'hotel')]");
for (WebElement link : links)
{
    System.out.println(link.getAttribute("href"));
}
```

Comment: Great! this does the job. It will great if I could do this with Xpath cause otherwise; I'm going to have to change a lot of other code.

Answer (score 0):

you can find all links on the page by:

```
".//a[@href]"
```

in your case:

```
List<WebElement> hotelElements = driver.findElementsByXPath(".//a[contains(href, 'hotel')]");
```

if you need to got hrefs from those links elements code will be something like:

```
List<string> hrefs = new List<string>();
foreach (var link in hotelElements )
{
    hrefs.Add (link.getAttribute("href"));
}
```

Comment: In the question he stated he wants to "extract all href links which starts with - /hotel/ or contains - hotel."

Comment: Thank you! However; I need the link only if it contains 'hotel' in it.

Comment: @JeffC : he asked for "correct Xpath location to extract all links from below HTML" =) I wrote this. He didn't ask [links to hotel]